# Paste Without Formatting won't work safari

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, safari, google-docs

I am able to use the "Paste Without Formatting" option in every browser except Safari. In Safari, neither the keyboard shortcut (Shift + Cmd + V) or menu>paste without formatting works. When I right-click, the option to paste (Cmd + V) is there, but paste without formatting is greyed out, along with several other options. Is this something that can be fixed, or is this just safari?

[image]

Comment: doesn't work for me either, probably safari has no option to pass the clipboard to the function to remove the formatting, as the right click is a page (google docs) functionality and not the browsers - you should post it to google help and et us know

Comment: @Zina Most likely google already knows about this problem, because the menu button doesn't grey itself out. However, I think I still will contact them to try and get more information on the problem.

Comment: That is not a Safari menu. It doesn't even look vaguely like any Mac menu. Safari doesn't have a 'Paste without formatting' option at all & neither do most Mac apps, they have a 'paste & match style' instead, cmd/shift/opt/V. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOzZa.png

Comment: @Tetsujin "Right-Click Menu". The menu that pops up when you right click on google docs

Comment: Then it's a Google Docs issue, that's not a Mac menu at all.

Answer (score 16):

Try `Cmd + Option + Shift + V` its working for me

Comment: If you read the comment thread you'll find the question itself was invalid. It's not a Safari issue, it's a Google Docs issue.

Comment: Yeah you are right @Tetsujin. But I tried with the shortcut which I mentioned I was able to paste without formatting.

Comment: I don't use G.Docs to be able to test, I'm afraid. My initial involvement in the question sprung from the posted image looking very un-Mac-like, nothing more really ;) I think I saw your answer in a review queue & just realised it was one I'd been involved in some while back.

Comment: @Tetsujin the popup menu is the GDoc popup menu, not the Mac popup menu.

Comment: It worked! But this is such a strange key combination lol, I can't enter it using only one hand

Comment: Apple should really get rid of any shortcuts longer than 2 keys. 3 is already painful to both memorize and press. 4 is downright egregious.

Answer (score 11):

This happens because Safari and Google Doc Shortcuts are clashing with one another. We cannot change Google Doc Shortcuts but we can change Safaris.

1. Just go to system preferences, then select keyboard, go to shortcuts then go to app shortcuts on the left hand side.
2. Once you've done that, click the plus button at the bottom and it should open another window, in that window, change the Application from all apps to safari, then add the following text: **Paste and Match Style** in the menu Title. (I am taking this command from when you click edit on Safari in the top menu.
3. Enter the shortcut as **Command Shift V**

For an easy guide, I have attached an image:

[image: click here for image]

Comment: Huge thanks, that's exactly what I was facing with Google Docs, and now pasting without formatting works with just Cmd+Shift+V

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom keyboard shortcut for Safari only that maps 'Paste and Match Style' to 'CMD-SHIFT-V' and you will have plain text pasting in Google Sheets, provided the target is plain text. Google Docs works too. You may have to re-launch Safari.

https://osxdaily.com/2017/08/08/create-custom-keyboard-shortcut-mac/